# Run delete project command only when the step above in Travis is executed successfully

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I want to run the
oc delete project command only if the the step above terminates with code 0

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the after_success [after_success](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/job-lifecycle/#the-job-lifecycle) tag.

> after_success - when the build succeeds (e.g. building documentation), the result is in TRAVIS_TEST_RESULT environment variable

The use of after_success tag allows to exec a give action only in case of success of the build.